# after jquery load scroll

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to scroll to the div that contains the results of a jquery load operation.
The ajax load works as expected but the page does not scroll after the load.
Why doesn't this test code do this?  Or, is there a better way?

Here is the test page that does not scroll after the load but
 does scroll if you then mouse click on the anchor hash tag 
 (Go to...):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>line 1</div>
<div>line 2</div>
  <a id="idGoTo" href="#scrollTo">Go to...</a>

  <a name="scrollTo">SI</a>
  <div id="divRightSide">
      <!--   ajax content here -->
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#divRightSide").load("/php/graduate/programs/clinical/programinformation_s.php", function() {
          $("#idGoTo").trigger("click");
          });
}
);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks Much for any consideration

Comment: Both Josh and Guruprasad Rao seem to be saying the same thing but neither works for me.

Comment: Both Josh and Guruprasad Rao seem to be saying the same thing but neither works for me.  Josh, I had to fix the ending to balance the '});' (syntax) but when executed the page did nothing.  Guruprasad Rao, this almost worked but it only scrolled about 1 line down , not to '#divRightSide'.  Guruprasad, thanks for the reference link though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the `.scrollTo` jQuery property

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#divRightSide").load("/php/graduate/programs/clinical/programinformation_s.php", function() {
     $('body').scrollTo('#idGoTo'); 
});
```

Comment: Josh Stevens, Guruprasad Rao.  I got both solutions to work.  I believe that I was not implementing the excellent plug-in 'scrollTo' by Ariel Flesler correctly.   I'm not sure how to up-tick your responses though.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.scrollTo` as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var _element=$("#divRightSide");
      _element.load("/php/graduate/programs/clinical/programinformation_s.php", function(){
           $('body').scrollTo("#"+_element.attr('id'));
      });
});
```

<kbd>**[`Reference`](http://lions-mark.com/jquery/scrollTo/)**</kbd>